# Binding Knockout subviewmodel to multiple views?

Tags: knockout.js, single-page-application

I'm stuck on a knockout JS binding issue. I have a master viewmodel that is bound to the shell  page of my single page application. This masterviewmodel controls which view is currently visible (Using Sammy JS). It also holds references to the sub viewmodels that are bound to the views.

```
var app = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.State = ko.observable('home');

    self.Home = ko.observable(new homepageVm());
    self.User = ko.observable(new userInfoVm());
    self.Request = ko.observable(new requestVm());
};
```

The User viewmodel has one view to bind to like this:

```
<div data-bind="with: User, visible: State() === 'user'">
    .. snip ..
</div>
```

The **with:** binding makes sure that the proper subviewmodel is bound to the view.
This approach works fine for both the home view and userinfo view.

The requestVm uses a wizard style UI and needs to bind to multiple views. This is where I'm currently stuck.

```
<div data-bind="with: Request, visible: State() === 'request-step-1'">
    .. snip ..
</div>

<div data-bind="with: Request, visible: State() === 'request-step-2'">
    .. snip ..
</div>

<div data-bind="with: Request, visible: State() === 'request-step-3'">
    .. snip ..
</div>
```

The bindings seem to work fine when I launch the site (Knockout is not throwing any binding errors) But when I start pushing data through the VMs they no longer update the UI, as if all the bindings are broken (even the ones that have a single view bound to them, such as the user VM).

If I include only the view of the first step of the wizard, which leaves me with only one binding on the Request VM instead of three, all the bindings in the app start working again!

I'm lost as to what is causing this. Is knockout only able to bind one observable to one single element? Or am I trying something unsupported?

**Update:**
It seems there is something going on with the observableArrays in my VM. The bindings to simple observables work fine.

Here is one of the VMs:

```
    function userInfoVm() {
    var self = this;

    self.UserName = ko.observable();

    self.Beun = ko.observable();

    self.LoadingUser = ko.observable(false);
    self.LoadingObjects = ko.observable(false);

    self.UserData = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.UserObjects = ko.observableArray([]);

    self.LoadUser = function (userName) {

        self.LoadingUser(true);

        $.get('UserData/UserDetail', { username: userName }, function (details) {
            self.UserData(details);
            self.Beun(JSON.stringify(details));

            self.LoadingUser(false);
        });
    };

    self.LoadObjects = function (userName) {

        self.LoadingObjects(true);

        $.get('UserData/UserObjects', { username: userName }, function (objects) {
            alert(JSON.stringify(objects));
            self.UserObjects([objects]);
            self.LoadingObjects(false);
        });
    };

    self.Load = function (userName) {
        self.UserName(userName);

        self.UserData(null);
        self.UserObjects(null);

        self.LoadUser(userName);
        self.LoadObjects(userName);
    };
};
```

And the view that is consuming the data from said VM:

```
<div data-bind="with: User, visible: State() === 'user'">
    <h1>
        <button class="backbutton" onclick="history.back();">
        </button>
        Details for user <span data-bind="text: UserName"></span>
    </h1>
    <div class="display detail">
        <table>
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: UserData">
                <tr>
                    <td class="property" data-bind="text: Key">
                    </td>
                    <td class="value" data-bind="text: Value">
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="loader" data-bind="visible: LoadingUser">
            Please wait while we process your request...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="display detail">
        <h1>
            Objects and services for user <span data-bind="text: UserName"></span>
        </h1>
        <table class="detailtable">
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: UserObjects">
                <tr>
                    <td class="value">
                        <a class="service" data-bind="text: Value, attr: { href: '#/service/' + Key }" href="#">
                        </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <div class="loader" data-bind="visible: LoadingObjects">
            Please wait while we process your request...
        </div>
    </div>
    Details for user <span data-bind="text: Beun"></span>
</div>
```

The arrays aren't notifing the UI about the data that is fed to them.
The other observables, including the .Beun one which contains the stringified data from the AJAX call are updated as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Whats the content you are recieving from the server?

You could try to convert the data (string) to objects with eval(objects) and convert those to an observable array using the  mapping plugin (knockout.mapping.js)  of within a foreach loop if you want to do it manually.

```
var data = '[{ "Id": 1, "Titel": "Title1", "Description": "Description 1" }, { "Id": 2, "Titel": "Title 2", "Description": "Description 2" }, { "Id": 3, "Titel": "Title 3", "Description": "Description 3"}]';
//fist convert your string to JS-objects using eval() ; then to observableArray using mapping pluging
self.UserObjects = ko.mapping.fromJS(eval(data));
```

Comment: The data is coming from the server as JSON. I've tried a few things, including manually handling the items from the server. Sadly I had to give up on the whole nested viewmodel system due to time constraints. I haven't given up entirely though, in a (much) smaller proof of concepts it did work as expected.